# System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<T> - is there a F# way?

Tags: f#, type-providers, c#-to-f#

I'm looking to use the F# WSDL Type Provider. To call the web service I am using, I need to attach my client credentials to the `System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials`.

This is the C# code I have:

```
var serviceClient = new InvestmentServiceV1Client.InvestmentServiceV1Client();

foreach (ClientCredentials behaviour in serviceClient.Endpoint.Behaviors.OfType<ClientCredentials>())
{
    (behaviour).UserName.UserName = USERNAME;
    (behaviour).UserName.Password = PASSWORD;
    break;
}
```

This is the F# code I have so far:

```
let client = new service.ServiceTypes.InvestmentServiceV1Client()
let xxx = client.Endpoint.Behaviors
|> Seq.choose (fun p -> 
    match box p with   
    :?   System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials as x -> Some(x) 
    _ -> None) 
|> (System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials)p.UserName.UserName = USERNAME
```

Is there an F# equivalent of `System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<T>` or should I just use raw `OfType<T>` ?

Comment: Any comments on the down votes? Or is that what happens after its edited?

Comment: I am guessing the down votes were for not showing any effort at translating the code (before your edit)

Comment: Ok lesson learnt. Comments on down votes would be good. Hopefully it's all good now if not please let me know and I'll expand (tomorrow as its late:))

Comment: The formatting was a disaster too - take few minutes to press Ctrl-K to unindent stuff etc. (my fix of that's been reverted). (I didnt downvote, but it doesn't encourage people to bother responding.). Also, I remove Thanks tailing.

Comment: +1 It's much better now. When I reformatted your code, the fact that you're using `=` instead of `<-` is the biggie for me (`=` is **always always** a comparison). Don't ask me how I know :) (Then again, my formatting is a guess and obv in F#, the formatting *matters*, **a lot**). Bottom line is, if @TomasPetrick is going to take 10 mins out of his day for me, I don't mind doing even 15 mins of legwork formatting a question properly and giving him (and others a the best chance of solving my problem first time) (Yes I know Tomas can do it in 2 mins really but you get my drift:D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose the question is mainly about the `break` construct, which is not available in F#. Well, the code really just sets the user name and password for the first element of the collection (or none, if the collection is empty). This can be done easily using pattern matching, if you turn the collection to an F# list:

```
// Get behaviours as in C# and convert them to list using 'List.ofSeq'
let sc = new InvestmentServiceV1Client.InvestmentServiceV1Client()
let behaviours = sc.Endpoint.Behaviors.OfType<ClientCredentials>() |> List.ofSeq

// Now we can use pattern matching to see if there is something in the list
match behaviours with
| behaviour::_ ->
    // And if the list is non-empty, set the user name and password
    behaviour.UserName.UserName <- USERNAME
    behaviour.UserName.Password <- PASSWORD
| _ -> ()
```

Comment: Hi Tomas - I have updated my question - hope its a bit clearer. Is there a better F# way to do this? (Otherwise will mark yours as correct) Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I see - I think there is no built-in equivalent to the `OfType` extension method. But using LINQ methods from F# is perfectly fine, so you can just continue using `OfType<T>`... (There is `Seq.cast<T>` but that just attempts to cast all elements, so that's not helpful here...)

Answer (score 4):

I think you've already implemented the F# equivalent of *.OfType()*. For emulating the *break* statement you can do as Tomas does in his answer (matching on list), or you call *Seq.head* (throws if there are no elements left), or you can do this:

```
let xxx = 
    client.Endpoint.Behaviors
    |> Seq.choose (function
        | :? System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials as x -> Some x
        | _ -> None ) 
    |> Seq.tryPick Some

match xxx with
| Some behavior -> ... // First element of required type found
| None -> ...          // No elements of required type at all in sequence
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - Ill merge both answers - wish I could double accept

Comment: Couldn't your `|> Seq.choose f |> Seq.tryPick Some` be simplified to just `|> Seq.tryPick f`?

Comment: @Tarmil: Oh yes, it could. But that wouldn't help for thinking in terms of _.OfType()_ and _.FirstOrDefault()_.