# How to find a parent visual in WPF using VisualTreeHelper in F#?

Tags: wpf, f#

(Newbie question). I have need to climb the visual tree of a wpf xaml until finding a parent Grid of x:Name "FindMe".  Assuming I have a visual child of "FindMe" called "grid", also a grid, how would I use the VisualTreeHelper in F# ?

```
let parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(grid) as Grid   <-- clearly wrong!
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call VisualTreeHelper.GetParent() recursively until you find it.

```
let rec getParent dp =
    match VisualTreeHelper.GetParent dp with
    | null -> None
    | :? Grid as grid when grid.Name = "FindMe" -> Some grid
    | parent -> getParent parent
```

Obviously this function could be made more general by passing in the type and name of the control you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `as` operator in F# but you could try this:

```
let parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(grid)
if parent :? Grid then
    ...
else
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a few type extensions to [`DependencyObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject?view=net-5.0) for climbing the visual tree parent hierarchy, then use them to search for a parent [`Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=net-5.0) with a specified name.

First define:

```
let inline isNull (x:^T when ^T : not struct) = obj.ReferenceEquals (x, null)

type DependencyObject with
    member t.GetVisualParents() =
        t |> Seq.unfold (fun state -> if isNull state then None else Some(state, VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(state))) 
          |> Seq.skip(1)
    member t.GetVisualParents<'T when 'T :> DependencyObject>() = 
        System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<'T>(t.GetVisualParents()) 
    member t.GetVisualParentByName<'T when 'T :> FrameworkElement>(name) = 
        t.GetVisualParents<'T> ()|> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.Name = name) |> Seq.tryHead
```

And then you can do:

```
let name = "FindMe"
let parent = grid.GetVisualParentByName<Grid>(name)
```

Notes:

- There is no `Seq.ofType` so I just used [`Enumerable.OfType<'T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0).  For other options see *[System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<T> - is there a F# way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19353818/3744182)* and *[F# Equivalent to Enumerable.OfType<'a>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2521254/3744182)*.
- [`Seq.tryHead`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#tryHead) was introduced in [f# 4.0](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/release-notes.md#400---20-july-2015).  If you are using an earlier version, you could use [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<'T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0) from `System.Linq`.